# Inputing a userinput to Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm new with python and mongo. I'm trying to make a piece of code that asks a question such as Enter username + password here: and the userinput goes into the mongo database. How do I go around doing that.

Comment: Hello.  Please provide your current code attempt so that the community can analyze it and provide suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How about starting with searching for "how do i accept data in python?". For the MongoDB aspect of it - to work with the database you need to use a driver program, it is the PyMongo.

Comment: Please make an attempt first and post the code you tried so that people can help with issues. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)